# Ajax request for autocomplete doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have an ajax request to get data of an autocomplete from my database.
This is my request :

```
$(function() {
    $("#client").autocomplete({
        minLength: 1,
        autoFocus: true,
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "jsonClients.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    q: request.term
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('success');
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This is the code for the input `<input type='text' id='client' name='client'>`. The data received looks ok from my browser console but nothing appens when I type something, the `alert('success')` isn't even displayed.

Note : My code is working on IE8 from the server, it isn't working on IE9/Firefox/Gchrome from my real windows session in intranet

Thanks!

Comment: try to add `.fail()` and `.always()`, see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @GuruprasadRao there is no errors in the console

Comment: @RobertStettler isn't it deprecated ?

Comment: From the jquery website: Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Comment: @RobertStettler it goes in .done and .always, never in .fail

Comment: Ok, then use the `error` callback besides the `success` callback and see, if that is called. `success: function(data) { ... }, error: function(data) { alert('there was an error'); } ....`

Comment: After adding the real function content in .done instead of just `alert('done');`, it goes in .fail with `parsererrorSyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Comment: @RobertStettler Here a screenshot from data received http://imgur.com/dwEgfh1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79500/discussion-between-robertstettler-and-xneyte).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found what was getting wrong.

For some reasons, the UTF8 encoding (From notepad++) makes the json_encoding bugging by causing a blank space at the beginning of result.

To resolve it, you just need to encode your files with UTF8 WITHOUT BOM and it'll no more have blank space so no more json_error like unexpected token or whatever.

Thanks for your help guys